# Conditional compilation based on functionality in Linux kernel headers

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, backwards-compatibility, perf

Consider the case where I'm using some functionality from the Linux headers exported to user space, such as [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) from `<linux/perf_event.h>`.

The functionality offered by this API has changed over time, as members have been added to the `perf_event_attr`, such as [`perf_event_attr.cap_user_time`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L422).

How can I write source that compiles and uses these new functionalities if they are available locally, but falls back gracefully if they aren't and doesn't use them?

In particular, how can I detect in the pre-processor whether this stuff is available?

I've used this `perf_event_attr` as an example, but my question is a general one because structure members, new structures, definitions and functions are added all the time.

Note that here I'm only considering the case where a process is compiled on the same system that it will run on: if you want to compile on one host and run on another you need a different set of tricks.

Comment: In the worst case: autoconf

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - yeah, exactly. Haven't introduced autoconf yet in this project, hope to avoid it.

Comment: Haven’t you seen the field `version`? All below answers are not accurate.

Comment: @0andriy - I have seen it. How could I used it to solve this problem?

Comment: Use it naturally. In your code something like `if (version == 1) { ... do for v1 ... } else ... `. Always compile against **latest** available API.

Comment: @0andriy - yeah type of runtime check only works if I could compile against the latest API, but that now how this thing works in practice: it is compiler against the local Linux headed such will correspond to the current OS.

Comment: You simple read as many bytes of the response as defined by the version of the protocol.

Comment: @0andriy - I wouldn't get that far because my compile will already have failed.

Comment: @0andriy Are you walking about the `perf_event_mmap_page.version` field? It doesn't appear to me that the `version` field reliably determines changes in the structure. For example, [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fa7315871046b9a4c48627905691dbde57e51033#diff-1baafe4a375405e90af42b7abc4e6c9b) commit adds new fields, but it doesn't seem change the version. Note also that the question is not specific to any Linux kernel type, so ultimately the Linux kernel version has to be used as discussed in the answers below.

Comment: @HadiBrais, it doesn't change neither sizeof, nor the backward compatibility: capabilities are a bit field where clear bit means no capability. All below answer are still inaccurate.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, you need to show, perhaps as another question, the problems you encounter with compilation. That is, the code reserves memory for a maximum size of the data structure it supports. When you call `ioctl(..., &my_data_struct)` it will fill it till the known size. Of course it is highly recommended to do `memset()` beforehand.

Comment: The problem is `cap_user_time` doesn't exist so the error is like `struct perf_whatever has no member named 'cap_user_time'`. You are really answering a different question: about ABI compatibility and determining at runtime how to populate a structure and which fields are written when dealing with multiple versions of an C, assuming you are compiling against the newest definition. I'm asking about compile-time determining the structure members since the binary will only be used on the host it was compiled on. @0andriy

Comment: `perf_event_mmap_page.version` and `perf_event_mmap_page.compat_version` are both `0` with Linux 5.1.4 - and I suspect they always have been. It also seems they are never written (other than being default-initialized with 0) or read *anywhere*.

Comment: @Zulan, the change that brought it in seems the fix for always broken stuff, so, basically we have only one *working* version for now on.

Comment: You are asking about structures that represent ABI at the end. Compile time members are defined by the headers in use, so if you don’t need to compile on older headers by some weird reason, the newest ones can be used and no error occurs.

Comment: @0andriy - have you ever compiled anything against Linux system headers? You get the headers that correspond to and are consistent the kernel in use, so on RHAT systems you often get headers from 2.6 + RHEL backports. So of course you need to compile on older headers "for some weird reason" (except not weird) for software distributed as source.

Answer (score 3):

Use the macros from `/usr/include/linux/version.h`:

```
#include <linux/version.h>

int main() {
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,16)
                                      // ^^^^^^ change for the proper version when `perf_event_attr.cap_user_time` was introduced
   // use old interface
#else
   // use new interface
   // use  perf_event_attr.cap_user_time
#endif
}
```

Comment: Inaccurate — note field `version`.

Comment: @0andriy `Inaccurate — note field version` ? Note what? What field? What is inaccurate? In what way?

Comment: @0andriy Until **you can't clearly expound** what the ... are you talking about - **your comments are inaccurate**. All answers can help to solve such problem well and all answers are quite accurate. **If you know more - compose the best answer.**

Comment: In the mentioned perf structure there is a `version` field. Even in general there is a good practice to put a version to an IOCTL ABI. If someone is not able to read a bit outside the box, it’s pity.

Answer (score 1):

You might go into this with the following assumptions

1. The features available in the header files correspond to those documented for the specific Linux version.
2. The kernel running during execution corresponds to `<linux/version.h>` during compilation

Ideally, I suggest **not** to rely on these two assumptions at all.

The first assumption fails primarily due to backports, e.g. in enterprise Linux versions based on ancient kernels. If you care about different versions, you probably care about them.

Instead, I recommend utilizing the methods for checking for struct members and include files in build system, e.g. for CMake:

```
CHECK_STRUCT_HAS_MEMBER("struct perf_event_attr" cap_user_time linux/perf_event.h HAVE_PERF_CAP_USER_TIME)
```

`CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES` can also be useful.

The second assumption can fail for many reasons, even if the binary is not moved between systems; E.g. updating the kernel but not recompiling the binary or simply booting another kernel. Specifically `perf_event_open` fails with `EINVAL` if a reserved bit is set. This allows you to retry with an alternative implementation not using the requested feature.

In short, statically check for the feature instead of the version. Dynamically, try and retry the legacy implementation if it failed.

Comment: Inaccurate — note field `version`.

Comment: @0andriy the `version` field in which struct?

Comment: In the `perf_event_attr` as mentioned by topic starter.

Comment: @0andriy `struct perf_event_attr ` does not have a field named `version`. Neither would it make sense if it had, since this struct contains information passed *from userspace to* the kernel.

Comment: it seems I didn’t carefully check the name of the structure. Nevertheless, one of them has `version`, another one has `size`. It doesn’t change the main motive of my comments.

Comment: @0andriy please post an answer, then we can properly discuss whether your approach has any merit.

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition to other answers.

If you're aiming for supporting both cross-version and cross-distro code, you should also keep in mind that there are distros (Centos/RHEL) which pull some recent changes from new kernels to old. So you may encounter a situation in which you'll have `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` equal to some old kernel version, but there will be some changes (new fields in data structures, new functions, etc.) from recent kernel. In such case this macro is insufficient.

You can add something like (to avoid preprocessor errors in case it is not a Centos distro):

```
#ifndef RHEL_RELEASE_CODE
#define RHEL_RELEASE_CODE 0
#endif
#ifndef RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION
#define RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(x,y) 1
#endif
```

And use it with `>` or `>=` where you need:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4,3,0) || RHEL_RELEASE_CODE > RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(7,2)
...
```

for Centos/RHEL custom kernels support.

P.S. of course it's necessary to examine an appropriate versions of Centos/RHEL, and understand when and what exactly has changed in the code sections that affect you.

Comment: The condition `RHEL_RELEASE_CODE > RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(7,2)` should probably be wrapped in `#ifdef RHEL_RELEASE_CODE` so that a compilation error doesn't occur when compiling on other Linux distros. Although using the `CHECK_STRUCT_HAS_MEMBER` method from @Zulan's answer might be easier than checking `RHEL_RELEASE_CODE`, unless there are cases where that doesn't work.

Comment: Inaccurate — note field `version`.

Comment: @0andriy What's wrong with my answer? Please clarify.

Comment: In the mentioned perf structure there is a `version` field. Even in general there is a good practice to put a version to an IOCTL ABI. Depending on it one may get a backward compatibility without ugly #ifdefs.

Comment: @0andriy You're talking about too specific use cases. Not every data structure in Linux kernel is a part of "API". So my answer is pretty accurate and more common. P.S. There is no uglinesses in such #ifdefs, this is absolutely normal.

Comment: IOCTL provides an ABI. How the user is suppose to know at **run time** the version of protocol? Every binary protocol, if designed correctly, has a versioning in one way, e.g. `version` field, or another, e.g. union type field.